# Figura geométrica com os dados em R

Tags: r

tenho 3 pontos e gostaria de formar um triângulo com eles, em seguida sobrepor outro triângulo com mais 3 novos pontos e assim sucessivamente.

Tentei assim, mas não consigo fazer o triângulo e os limites dos gráficos seguintes são ignorados.

```
a = matrix(c(rnorm(6)), ncol = 2)
b = matrix(c(rnorm(6)), ncol = 2)
d = matrix(c(rnorm(6)), ncol = 2)
plot(a[,1]~a[,2],pch = 16)
par(new = T)
plot(b[,1]~b[,2], axes = F, ann = F, pch = 16, col = "red")
par(new = T)
plot(d[,1]~d[,2], axes = F, ann = F, pch = 16, col = "green")
```

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Olá man, são diversos triângulos, eu quero gerar aleatoriamente as coordenadas e plotar um sobre o outro. Por exemplo, gero 150 coordenadas aí ploto 50 triângulos um sobrepondo o outro. (150 foi só um exemplo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu montei duas funções, uma para criar as coordenadas aleatórias de um triângulo e uma para plotar os `n` triângulos de coordenadas aleatórias que você quiser. O código está bem bruto, mas acho que atende ao que você queria.

#### código

```
# Pacote que a gente vai usar, muito bom pra gerar gráficos
require(ggplot2)

# função para gerar coordernadas aleatórias do triângulo
geraTriangulo <- function() data.frame(x = rnorm(3), y = rnorm(3))

# função para plotar o triângulo
plotTriangulo <- function(n) {
  g = ggplot()
  for(i in 1:n){
    g <- g + geom_polygon(data = geraTriangulo(), aes(x = x, y = y), 
      colour="black", fill = NA)
  }
  print(g)
}
```

#### exemplo

```
#input
> plotTriangulo(200) #criará 200 triângulos aleatórios sobrepostos

#output
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]